Place components in specific shapes Proteus 8
Is any method to place components in circle shape?
I need to place 20 LEDs on circle diameter (20mm) with same spacing (In CAD SW is used some "circular pattern" where select degree, spacing, how many instances, and so on) and also create a PCB with 30mm diameter circle.
Could you please help me? Thank you in advance!
